# Pass function from angular1 to downgraded angular2 component

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade, angular2-upgrade

**Problem:**

I am unable to get a function to pass successfully to a downgraded Angular 2 component. I've tried just about every way I can think to pass things in but I am only able to get strings passed in via string interpolation -> some-attribute={{controller.property}}. Here are some of the things I've tried (yes, I know some of them don't make sense...)

```
some-function="controller.function";
some-function="{{controller.function}}";  //<-- works for data, not functions
[some-function]="{{controller.function}}";
[someFunction]="controller.function";
[(someFunction)]="controller.function";
```

**Setup:**

Here is my existing setup which is working for data but not for functions:

Angular 1 usage

```
<my-component data-input-name="{{controller.name}}"></my-component>
```

Upgrade/Downgrade adapter

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myComponent',
    downgradeComponent({
      component: MyComponent, 
      inputs: ['inputName']
    }) as angular.IDirectiveFactory);
```

Angular 2 definition

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() inputName: any;

  constructor() {}
}
```

The [Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/upgrade/static/downgradeComponent-function.html) even show how to set it up but they don't give any examples of actual usage.
Am I missing something or can this just not be done?

Answer (score 3):

Use AngularJS kebab case like this, seems to work for me:

```
<my-component [data-input-name]="controller.name">
</my-component>
```